# How can I update the UI using a broadcast receiver?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I need to update the UI using a brodcast receiver. I written this code but I dont see any update of the UI when I debug.

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Android.Content.Intent.ActionTimeTick })]
private class broadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    private _MyActivityact;
    public void broadCastReceiver(_MyActivity act)
    {
        this.act = act;
    }

    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        _MyActivity.RunOnUiThread(() => {
                     updateUI(intent);   
        });                     
    }

    private void updateUI(Intent intent)
    {
        float mstartx = _MyActivity.getmStartX();
        TextView startx = _MyActivity.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.startx);
        startx.SetText(Convert.ToChar(mstartx));                 
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you verified that updateUI actually gets called?

Comment: Yes I am verifing that and it is not called at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you can't subscribe to [ActionTimeTick](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_TIME_TICK) the way you do. From the documentation:

> Broadcast Action: The current time has changed. Sent every minute. **You
>   cannot receive this through components declared in manifests**, only by
>   explicitly registering for it with Context.registerReceiver().

In Xamarin, the [IntentFilter](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.App.IntentFilterAttribute/) attribute is used by monodroid.exe when generating the `intent-filter` elements in the  AndroidManifest.xml file so that won't work.

What you need to do, is remove the `IntentFilter` attribute and register the receiver programmatically in your `MainActivity` (for example).

```
protected override void OnResume()
{
    base.OnResume();
    RegisterReceiver(yourReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent. ActionTimeTick));
}

protected override void OnPause()
{
    base.OnPause();
    UnregisterReceiver(yourReceiver);
}
```